# How do I solve ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: node.js, async-await, babeljs, async.js, babel-polyfill

I've seen that issue a lot here but none of the solutions worked for me. I'm using NodeJS and had no issue until I changed the project's directory.

Since then I can't get my code to work...

I've included:

```
import "@babel/polyfill"
```

I'm using async / await and this is clearly what's causing the issue:

```
async function process_data(post) {
// my_code
}
```

If I write the code like that:

```
const test = async function process_data(post) {
// my code
}
```

That's working but I can no longer call the `process_data` method on its own with the parameter (or else, I don't know how do it).

Any idea how I can get that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By tweaking the code I found the answer:

```
const my_func = async function process_data(post) {
// my code
}

var res = my_func(post_var);
```